# Python MapReduce : Empty file from mapper

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

**join2_mapper.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
shows = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line       = line.strip()   
    key_value  = line.split(',')

    if key_value[1] == 'ABC':
        if key_value[1] not in shows:
            shows.append(key_value[0])

    if key_value[1].isdigit() and (key_value[0] in shows):
        print('{0}\t{1}'.format(key_value[0], key_value[1]) )
```

**sample i/p**

```
Hourly_Sports,DEF
Baked_Games,ABC
Dumb_Talking,ABC
Surreal_Talking,DEF
Cold_Sports,BAT
Hourly_Talking,XYZ
Baked_Talking,CNO
PostModern_Games,ABC
Loud_Talking,DEF
Almost_News,BAT
Hot_Talking,XYZ
Dumb_News,CNO
Surreal_News,ABC
Cold_Talking,DEF
Hourly_Show,BAT
Baked_Show,XYZ
PostModern_Talking,CNO
Loud_Show,ABC
Almost_Cooking,DEF
Hot_News,BAT
Dumb_Cooking,XYZ
Surreal_Cooking,CNO
Cold_News,ABC
Hourly_Sports,DEF
Baked_Sports,BAT
PostModern_Show,XYZ
Loud_Sports,CNO
Almost_Games,ABC
Hot_Cooking,DEF
Dumb_Games,BAT
Surreal_Games,XYZ
Cold_Cooking,CNO
Hourly_Talking,ABC
Baked_Talking,DEF
PostModern_Sports,BAT
Loud_Talking,XYZ
Almost_Talking,CNO
Hot_Games,ABC
Dumb_Talking,DEF
Surreal_Talking,BAT
Cold_Games,XYZ
Hourly_News,CNO
Baked_News,ABC
PostModern_Talking,DEF
Loud_News,BAT
Almost_Show,XYZ
Hot_Talking,CNO
Dumb_Show,ABC
Surreal_Show,DEF
Cold_Talking,BAT
Hourly_Cooking,XYZ
Baked_Cooking,CNO
PostModern_News,ABC
Loud_Cooking,DEF
Almost_Sports,BAT
Hot_Show,XYZ
Dumb_Sports,CNO
Surreal_Sports,ABC
Cold_Show,DEF
Hourly_Games,BAT
Baked_Games,XYZ
PostModern_Cooking,CNO
Loud_Games,ABC
Almost_Talking,DEF
Hot_Sports,BAT
Dumb_Talking,XYZ
Surreal_Talking,CNO
Cold_Sports,ABC
Hourly_Talking,DEF
Baked_Talking,BAT
PostModern_Games,XYZ
Loud_Talking,CNO
Almost_News,ABC
Hot_Talking,DEF
Dumb_News,BAT
Surreal_News,XYZ
Cold_Talking,CNO
Hourly_Show,ABC
Almost_Cooking,855
Baked_Games,991
Baked_News,579  
Baked_Games,200 
Baked_Games,533
Cold_News,590
Hourly_Show,896
```

`$ cat j2.txt | python join2_mapper.py`

```
Baked_Games 991
Baked_News  579
Baked_Games 200
Baked_Games 533
Cold_News   590
Hourly_Show 896
```

`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar    -input /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_genchan*.txt -input /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_gennum*.txt    -output /user/cloudera/join2_f1f    -mapper /home/cloudera/join2_mapper.py    -reducer /home/cloudera/join2_reducer.py    -numReduceTasks 0`

```
Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=6600
        Map output records=0
        Input split bytes=759
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=4419
        CPU time spent (ms)=9170
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=702300160
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=9022578688
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=364511232
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=113055
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
```

The issue is with the input files. I have actually six input files as follows:

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_gen*.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera       1714 2015-11-07 12:24 /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_genchanA.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera       3430 2015-11-07 12:24 /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_genchanB.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera       5152 2015-11-07 12:24 /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_genchanC.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera      17114 2015-11-07 12:24 /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_gennumA.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera      34245 2015-11-07 12:24 /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_gennumB.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera      51400 2015-11-07 12:24 /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_gennumC.txt
```

When i concatenate all the files into a single file and run the job it is working. Getting the desired result. When provided the input files in six chunks I get an empty file. Please advise.

Comment: Please can I see your reducer? You refer to one in the execution command, but the code for it is missing. Also your two input commands could be replaced with `-input /user/cloudera/join2_data/join2_gen*.txt`.

Comment: Since I have specified numReduceTasks = 0, the reducer will not be executed right? Please correct me if I am wrong. As the file is empty from the mapper, the reducer throws error. I have tested the reducer with another mapper, it works well. I don't think there is a problem with reducer. I can post the reducer if required.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Hadoop Streaming with Python, but I would try not specifying the `-reducer` option? Granted it shouldn't change anything, but it's worth a try. Also what happens if you pass `j2.txt` into the job? it seems to be a different file to the inputs you've actually used.

Comment: Sure. I will try and update you. j2.txt is just a sample, the actual file is pretty big. I have tried the actual file mentioned in the hadoop command in shell, got the desired output.

Comment: OK cool. One last thing - all examples I can find online have the `-file` arguments - `hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar \
    -mapper mapper.py \
    -reducer reducer.py \
    -input nfldata/stadiums \
    -output nfldata/pythonoutput \
    -file simple/mapper.py \
    -file simple/reducer.py`. It could be worth adding your mapper in that way?

Comment: @BenWatson I just found the issue. Updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Only provide one `-input` argument, and pass it the path to a folder containing all of your input data rather than using regex. Also remove the reducer if you're not using it (just to de-clutter). I can't exactly say which of these will resolve the issue (I suspect it's the first), but it will fix it. So:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input /user/cloudera/join2_data/ \
-output /user/cloudera/join2_f1f \
-mapper /home/cloudera/join2_mapper.py
```

Comment: Tried `$ hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -input /user/cloudera/join2_data/ -output /user/cloudera/join2_txt3 -mapper /home/cloudera/join2_mapper.py`
Still the same. 
`File Input Format Counters 
  Bytes Read=113055
 File Output Format Counters 
  Bytes Written=0`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean to have `key_value[0]` instead of 1, in `if key_value[1] not in shows`?

Comment: The first half of the file has shows and channels and the second half contains shows and counts. I am creating a list of shows that is hosted in ABC and then sending only the ABC's shows and its counts to reducer. In a nut shell, I am trying to find the counts of each shows that is hosted in ABC alone. So the logic is fine.